# How to update or create records through polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I'd like to update or create the data array through the polymorphic.

```
class Freelancer < ActiveRecord
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Client < ActiveRecord
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addressable
end
```

I'd like to use this kind of params on the other controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new params
    params.require(:user).permit([
      ...
      addresses_attributes: [
        :id, :position, :addressable_type, :addressable_id,
        addressable_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]
      ]
    ])
  end
end
```

The data from frontend is

```
user: {
  addresses_attributes: [{
   id: 1, position:0, addressable_type: 'Client', addressable_id:12,
   addressable_attributes: {id: 1, first_name: 'Jone', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'jonedoe@gmail.com'}
  },{
   id:'', position:1, addressable_type: 'Freelancer', addressable_id:'',
   addressable_attributes: {id: '', first_name: 'Jone1', last_name: 'Doe1', email: 'jonedoe1@gmail.com'}
  }]
}
```

From this kind of data, I'd like to update it, if one of the attributes in the array has its id, and create it if it doesn't have on all tables.

How do I have to handle this?

Comment: Have you checked this - https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've checked it but I can't find the solution. Would you be able to write the answer here?

Comment: What should `addressable_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]` create, a `Freelancer` or `Client`? Is this server determined or can the client pick the addressable type?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks for the comment. It's client determined